# How do I sort an array of Swift dictionaries by key

Tags: swift

There are similar questions, but they don't seem to address my situation. I am hoping someone brighter than me has some insight into how I can accomplish this. I have a Swift array of dictionaries, in the format:

```
[[NSDate: Double]]
```

Currently, my array currently looks like this:

```
[[2016-02-09 17:20:51 +0000: 0.0], [2016-02-05 17:20:51 +0000: 0.0], [2016-02-08 17:20:51 +0000: 233.0], [2016-02-07 17:20:51 +0000: 88.0], [2016-02-06 17:20:51 +0000: 88.0], [2016-02-04 17:20:51 +0000: 196.0], [2016-02-03 17:20:51 +0000: 961.0]]
```

I want to re-order it so that the array is sorted by the date of each dictionary's key.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary if you suppose there is always one date and one numeric value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
let dicts = [[NSDate: Double]]()

let sortedDicts = dicts.sort { (dict1, dict2) in
    if let date1 = dict1.keys.first,
        date2 = dict2.keys.first {
        return date1.compare(date2) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    return false
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let dicts = [[Date: Double]]()

let sortedDicts = dicts.sorted { (dict1, dict2) in
    if let date1 = dict1.keys.first,
        date2 = dict2.keys.first {
        return date1.compare(date2) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `arr` is your array of one-element dictionaries, and if your reference to `arr` is a `var` reference, then I would write

```
arr.sortInPlace {$0.keys.first!.timeIntervalSince1970 < $1.keys.first!.timeIntervalSince1970}
```

But I agree with Sulthan's comment that an array of one-element dictionaries is a very strange data structure. It would make more sense just to have a dictionary (of date-double pairs). It has no order, but it is trivial to extract from it an array (of date-double pairs) in order.

Answer (score 2):

```
var datesDict:[[NSDate:Double]] = [[NSDate():0.1], [NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60):1.1], [NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60):0.1]]
print(datesDict)
datesDict.sortInPlace { (item1:[NSDate:Double], item2:[NSDate:Double]) -> Bool in
    return item1.keys.first?.compare(item2.keys.first!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Basically you use the sortInPlace function on arrays and in the comparison block compare the keys which are date objects and return true if its ascending else false. This works well in playground, so should work for you too.